# 'I about to died' --- Southern vernacular?

Tags: dialects

I wonder if anyone here has ever heard this phrase, *about to* + past tense --- probably a dialectal variant of *about* + past tense. Is this America's Southern vernacular?

> And then the judge turned to Gavin: “It's so nice to meet you. I've
>   heard so much about you.”
>
> **I about to died**: *heard so much about you!* It was as if he was
>   meeting a fellow at the Tuesday Rotary luncheon. Even Gavin was
>   impressed. (['Everybody's all American'](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=n0mSSUrmoJ8C&pg=PT98&lpg=PT98&dq=%22I%20about%20to%20died%22&source=bl&ots=8ixa8kHlwY&sig=ACfU3U2KKcupMdxzxKZEn0QXbU6zUupHgg&hl=ja&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjsNjr6sPnAhVdIqYKHam6C1EQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20about%20to%20died%22&f=false) by Frank Deford)

Comment: It's a common idiom.  Probably more common in the Southeast US, but would be recognized anywhere.

Comment: Isn't 'to' unnecessary? What do you parse 'to' as? To my non-native speaker's ear, it doesn't sound it came from anywhere grammatical. Yet, idioms doesn't have to be grammatical. Right.